# Manual TLS decryption with master secret

Tags: tls, decryption, tls-intercept

Assuming I have the master secret from SSLKEYLOGFILE client random, and server random, can I decrypt any tls traffic captured? I've started from Golang's TLS implementation, pulled the connection stuff out, had it generate the keys and iv from the values above (https://github.com/golang/go/blob/cd18da451faedc4218a5fd0e38f9b3d13aa5da01/src/crypto/tls/prf.go#L121), but still can't decrypt.

Thoughts? Is one able to generally decrypt any TLS (given correct version and cipher) with one instance implementation, like Golang's?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Yes - if you have this information you can use to decrypt the traffic which you can easily reproduce when doing this with Wireshark. It does not matter which TLS stack was involved in producing the traffic as long as you have the correct information in the expected format. It is unclear for me from your question what you exactly are asking and what this has to do with Golang.

Comment: Yeah, ok. I was wondering if I use a stack that neither the client or server in a TLS communication have used, if I can still decrypt it having those parameters above.

Comment: TLS is a standard. That's why independent implementations can work together - no matter if as client and server or to decrypt sniffed content provided the necessary information are given.